# OP deleted original question, and then asked same (or similar) question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Do these two questions need special handling? The OP deleted the original question, and then asked same (or similar) question:

- [AVL Tree not inserting/deleting properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26317110) (deleted)
- [AVL Tree flawed logic with insertion/deletion/balancing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26319871)

I guess I'm confused by the deletion. The question was *not* downvoted and it had an answer.

---

For those who don't have the points, here is the deleted question:

[image]

And here is the new question (sans the expected output):

[image]

Comment: @Jongware - the thing about this situation (and question) is the original question was *not* not well received (???). Its why I am confused, and its why I wonder if anything should be done. The only downside I see are the person who answered the first question lost his work. The other potential downside is the OP is not learning to use the site correctly But that does not appear to be a high priority on SO. So its hard to complain about user education.

Comment: The OP - new to SO by the look of his rep - may have been scared off by the Close-votes and may need some instruction on how to edit his own post. (And not including textual output in an image.)

Comment: @Jongware you need a rep of 250 to view close votes on your own questions. Although there might have been comments saying it was off-topic, bad etc.

Comment: @Jongware is right -- *inform* them of what SO policies are. And if they don't listen... well, we have a post ban for that.